# How can we update product price in Magento using SQL

Tags: sql, magento

I am trying this SQL query to update the product price 7% in magento but cannot get any luck can anyone please help me on that.

```
  UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal val
  SET  val.value = (val.value)
  WHERE  val.attribute_id = (
     SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
     WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4 
       AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
```

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: you are missing the closing parenthesis in the subquery

Comment: Thanks @zip I have posted a running query and that update all my prices all over in magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the running query.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal
 SET value = value * 1.07
 WHERE attribute_id IN (
SELECT attribute_id FROM mage_eav_attribute 
WHERE attribute_code IN ('price'))
AND `value` > 0;
```

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_group_price 
SET value = value * 1.07;
```